# Is my HDD toast?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive

My hard disk keeps getting remounted in read-only mode.  Disk is a 1.5TB external USB2 on Debian squeeze (armv5tel).

Had similar errors previously so reformatted with a full surface scan (`mkfs.ext4 -cc`), and all went well.

Output of `dmesg`:

```
[494984.513516] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[494984.518422] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[494984.525707] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 1d 2d 4c b0 00 00 f0 00
[494984.532907] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 489508016
[494984.538768] __ratelimit: 20 callbacks suppressed
[494984.543504] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188246
[494984.549884] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.554975] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188247
[494984.561359] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.566447] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188248
[494984.572835] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.577914] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188249
[494984.584302] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.589381] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188250
[494984.595768] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.600847] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188251
[494984.607235] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.612314] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188252
[494984.618702] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.623788] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188253
[494984.630169] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.635256] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188254
[494984.641636] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494984.646723] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188255
[494984.653111] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494987.223018] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494989.012890] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494990.552897] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494992.002891] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494993.362767] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494995.182769] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494995.293262] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[494995.298165] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[494995.305457] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 1d 2d 4d a0 00 00 f0 00
[494995.312659] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 489508256
[494995.318519] __ratelimit: 20 callbacks suppressed
[494995.323255] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188276
[494995.329635] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.334726] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188277
[494995.341110] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.346199] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188278
[494995.352596] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.357674] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188279
[494995.364062] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.369140] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188280
[494995.375528] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.380607] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188281
[494995.386995] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.392074] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188282
[494995.398461] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.403549] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188283
[494995.409928] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.415016] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188284
[494995.421395] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494995.426483] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188285
[494995.432871] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[494997.462642] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[494999.012647] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495000.532642] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495002.282639] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495004.042485] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495005.512516] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495005.623011] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[495005.627911] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[495005.635205] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 1d 2d 4e 90 00 00 f0 00
[495005.642406] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 489508496
[495005.648266] __ratelimit: 20 callbacks suppressed
[495005.653001] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188306
[495005.659382] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.664475] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188307
[495005.670858] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.675946] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188308
[495005.682342] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.687420] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188309
[495005.693808] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.698887] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188310
[495005.705275] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.710354] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188311
[495005.716742] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.721820] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188312
[495005.728208] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.733296] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188313
[495005.739675] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.744763] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188314
[495005.751142] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495005.756230] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61188315
[495005.762618] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495008.292391] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495009.582391] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495011.292265] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495011.992245] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495012.692264] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495013.372263] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495013.482765] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[495013.487666] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[495013.494958] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 1d 2c e7 e0 00 00 f0 00
[495013.502160] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 489482208
[495013.508021] __ratelimit: 20 callbacks suppressed
[495013.512755] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185020
[495013.519137] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.524227] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185021
[495013.530611] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.535700] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185022
[495013.542088] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.547167] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185023
[495013.553554] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.558634] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185024
[495013.565021] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.570099] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185025
[495013.576487] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.581567] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185026
[495013.587955] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.593042] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185027
[495013.599421] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.604509] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185028
[495013.610888] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495013.615976] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 61185029
[495013.622363] lost page write due to I/O error on sdb1
[495040.901517] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495071.540643] usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device using orion-ehci and address 35
[495079.416152] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sdb1-8
[495079.430261] Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
[495079.441567] EXT4-fs (sdb1): delayed block allocation failed for inode 28579023 at logical offset 466156 with max blocks 2048 with error -30
[495079.454361] This should not happen!!  Data will be lost
[495079.460555] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1) in ext4_da_writepages: IO failure
[495079.471089] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1) in ext4_da_writepages: Journal has aborted
[495079.480699] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
[495079.488935] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[495079.494657] EXT4-fs (sdb1): ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 11 pages, ino 28579023; err -30
[495079.518788] EXT4-fs (sdb1): ext4_da_writepages: jbd2_start: 2147481583 pages, ino 28579023; err -30
[495079.685465] rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: got error -104 when sending 124 bytes - shutting down socket
[495079.694028] rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: got error -32 when sending 124 bytes - shutting down socket
[495079.702653] rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: got error -32 when sending 124 bytes - shutting down socket
[495079.711519] rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: got error -32 when sending 124 bytes - shutting down socket
[495079.719943] nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!
[495079.725745] nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!
[495079.730564] nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!
[495079.735064] nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!
[508407.944942] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be that these errors are the disk failing, or it could just be the board that is being used to abstract to USB.

If these errors occur frequently, you may want to limit the scope of the issue by removing the disk from its enclosure, disconnecting the hard drive from the board abstracting to USB, and attaching it directly using SATA. This way you can get SMART information from the disk, and have a faster interface than USB if you need to image the disk in a hurry (for example, due to imminent failure). If these problems don't occur when the disk is attached directly via SATA, then it is probably just the board being used by your enclosure that needs replacing.

Comment: I can access the SMART data even over USB: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aRxzegQ5